# Infinite loop with React comonentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a parent App component that renders a route with a Report component.  The App component makes an ajax call in its componentDidMount method and the Report also makes some ajax calls in its componentDidUpdate method, at which point it calls the parent's updateReports method.  The app is stuck in an infinite loop where the child keeps making its ajax calls over and over again.

App

```
...
  updateReports(report) {
    console.log('updateReports', report)
    if (report.submittal) {
      this.setState({ reports: { submittal: report.submittal } });
      if (report.specification) {
        this.setState({ reports: { specification: report.specification } });
      }
    }
  }
...    
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('environment', process.env);
    console.log('App state', this.state);
    if (!this.state.projectName) {
      const err = new Error('Project Name must be supplied in the url: /<projectName>');
      return this.handleError(err);
    }

    this.populateProjectId();
  }

  populateProjectId() {
    return Api.getProjectId(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH, this.state.projectName)
      .then((projectId) => {
        console.log('App adding projectId to state', projectId);
        this.setState({ projectId });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.handleError(err);
      });
  }
...
  render() {
const commonProps = {
  query: this.state.query,
  projectName: this.state.projectName,
  projectId: this.state.projectId
};
...
            <Route
              path="/:projectName/admin"
              render={(props) => (
                <Admin
                  {...{ ...commonProps }} reports={this.state.reports}
                  updateReports={this.updateReports}
                  handleError={this.handleError}
                />
              )}
            />
```

Admin

```
...
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log('Admin componentDidUpdate')
    const { projectId } = this.props;

    const apiPath = process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH;
    Api.fetchReport(apiPath, projectId, 'submittal', null)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('submittal report result', res);
        return res;
      })
      .then((submittal) => {
        Api.fetchReport(apiPath, projectId, 'specification', null).then((res) => {
          console.log('specification report result', res);
          const newState = { submittal, specification: res };
          console.log('Calling updateReports', newState);
          this.props.updateReports(newState);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.handleError(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Report reports={this.props.reports} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Admin));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ComponentDidUpdate() will be called whenever the props for the child component are updated.

In this scenario the flow happening is:

1. `reports={this.state.reports}` is passed to the child component
2. The child is then updated because it's `reports` prop changed
3. ComponentDidUpdate() is called, and subsequently triggers `updateReports(newState)` in the parent component
4. In the parent component the state is updated with the new reports
5. The updated `reports={this.state.reports}` is passed to the Child
6. Repeat 2-5

Using ComponentDidMount() in this scenario should fix the issue, but more importantly from a solution architecture perspective, your service call should extracted into a separate file and called from the parent, making the child a dumb component.

There's plenty I could say but i'm just here to clarify why the loop is occuring :P

Comment: what if I only want to make the call when the child route is loaded? What's the best way to handle it?

Comment: Everything depends on the frequency you need those reports updated... On the `ComponentDidMount()` of your parent is the best place to make the call only once and then just pass it to your child, and take all the functionality out, alternatively that method in the child in most cases will only be called once.

You can also make service calls on the `constructor()` but it's usually not best practice.